# 13.04, Thinkpad x230, I/O Errors after 15-20 minutes working

Tags: 13.04, ssd, thinkpad, read-only

After last update my system became behave strange. After 15-20 minutes all drives become read only. In terminal I get errors: I/O error, Bus error, disk is read only.

I checked all my disks by smartctl, everything is ok.

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)       LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5681         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5680         -

$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
```

Part of dmesg: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zTqVmKJKyDI/UbwqiV5hxDI/AAAAAAAAV7U/nOrATeHVgIw/w733-h550-no/IMG_20130615_114744.jpg

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
└─sda2   8:2    0 238.5G  0 part /home/vitali
sdb      8:16   0  59.6G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0  59.6G  0 part /


$ sudo lshw -class disk
  *-disk:0                
       description: ATA Disk
       product: M4-CT256M4SSD2
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 0009
       serial: 000000001141031BD111
       size: 238GiB (256GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=000240d5
  *-disk:1
       description: ATA Disk
       product: SATA SSD
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: S5FA
       serial: 1B650715132200000086
       size: 59GiB (64GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=0bb2e31f
```

I tried to move my system from sdb to sda, but nothing changed.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=~/sdb1.img
dd if=~/sdb1.img of=/dev/sda1
```

Kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux sab 3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:30 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

How can I find my problem and fix it?

Comment: First of all: Don't use `dd` on SSDs especially not if TRIM is activated.

Comment: Both disks are affected? I know about certain Crucial M4 disks failing, it could be a coincidence. Have you tried one of the previous kernels?

Comment: Yes, are both. 

Rebooted to previous kernel:
$ uname -a
Linux sab 3.8.0-24-generic

Comment: Your uname output is a little short. Mine is `$ uname -a
Linux za20 3.5.0-32-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 29 20:23:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` You are running the default Ubuntu kernel, aren't you?

Comment: I just cut it:    
$ uname -a
Linux sab 3.8.0-24-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 31 14:09:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Are you using EXT4 and added the `discard` option that activates TRIM support in `fstab`? Have you tried disabling it? Have you run a filesystem check? Have you tried using the disks in another computer?

Comment: If the error persists I suggest backing up the data on the filesystems (on another computer if possible and as soon as possible if you haven't already), creating new partition tables and filesystems and copying the data from the backups. You probably don't need to reinstall Ubuntu, just copy (`cp -a` or `rsync -a`) the contents of your old root filesystem to the newer one, edit `fstab`, edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, update and reinstall GRUB to MBR.

Comment: Note: Please avoid doing `dd` backups of drives with questionable status. It puts to much stress on the drive and may make things worse. (Imagine an interrogation like: "What's block 000000001? What's block 000000002? ... What's block 999999999?")

Comment: Changing kernel - don't help, I will try make backup.

Comment: I added 'discard' to fstab after your first commit. Yes, I checked disks by fsck.ext4. 
I copied(cp -a) data from sdb1 to new ext4 sda1 and booted from sda1. If it's couldn't help, I'm going to move sda disk to another notebook for test.

Comment: It is Crucial M4 hardware problem. I have the same errors on another notebook. Thanks, for help.

Comment: If that solves your issue, please add it as an answer and mark you question as answered. Thank you.

Comment: I fixed my problem with Crucial M4 SSD by upgrading firemware from 0009 to 070H.